# Why do these two Counts return the same number?

Tags: php, postgresql, count

```
$SQL = "SELECT pc.dist_id, pc.route, pc.types,
        COUNT( pc.types = '$type' ) total,
        COUNT( pc.types = '$type' AND pc.options = '1') callbacks

        FROM per_call pc
        WHERE pc.types = '$type'
        GROUP BY pc.dist_id, pc.route, pc.types
        ORDER BY pc.dist_id, pc.route";
```

In short, I guess I'm asking how COUNT works with multiple columns inside the ().

Comment: For the record: `psql` is the tag for the command line terminal of PostgreSQL. Please tag properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Count` will work as well :

```
SELECT pc.dist_id, pc.route, pc.types,
COUNT( CASE WHEN pc.types = '$type' THEN 1 END) total,
COUNT( CASE WHEN pc.types = '$type' AND pc.options = '1' THEN 1 END) callbacks

FROM per_call pc
WHERE pc.types = '$type'
GROUP BY pc.dist_id, pc.route, pc.types
ORDER BY pc.dist_id, pc.route
```

Note: it works because `COUNT` returns count of the number of non-NULL values, and `CASE` has default `ELSE NULL` ...

Answer (score 1):

Another, slightly shorter variant (performance is about the same as with a `CASE` statement):

```
SELECT pc.dist_id, pc.route, pc.types
      ,COUNT(NULLIF(pc.types = '$type', FALSE) AS total
      ,COUNT(NULLIF(pc.types = '$type' AND pc.options = '1', FALSE) AS callbacks
FROM   per_call pc
WHERE  pc.types = '$type'
GROUP  BY pc.dist_id, pc.route, pc.types
ORDER  BY pc.dist_id, pc.route;
```

The principal behind it is this:
`COUNT` counts all non-null values.
The expressions yield a boolean value which can be `TRUE`, `FALSE` or `NULL`.
You only want to count the `TRUE` case.
So convert `FALSE` to `NULL` and everything is groovy.

Or, even shorter, but not faster:

```
SELECT pc.dist_id, pc.route, pc.types
      ,sum((pc.types = '$type')::int) AS total
      ,sum((pc.types = '$type' AND pc.options = '1')::int) AS callbacks
FROM   per_call pc
WHERE  pc.types = '$type'
GROUP  BY pc.dist_id, pc.route, pc.types
ORDER  BY pc.dist_id, pc.route;
```

Coercing `boolean` to `integer`, `TRUE` converts to 1, `FALSE` to 0. Therefore, `sum()` works.

And since you have `pc.types = '$type'` as `WHERE` condition, you can simplify to:

```
SELECT pc.dist_id, pc.route, pc.types
      ,COUNT(*) AS total  -- slightly faster, too
      ,COUNT(NULLIF(pc.options = '1', FALSE) AS callbacks
FROM   per_call pc
WHERE  pc.types = '$type'
GROUP  BY pc.dist_id, pc.route, pc.types
ORDER  BY pc.dist_id, pc.route;
```